# opensmile in Python save as .arff

Tags: weka, feature-extraction, arff, audio-analysis, audeering-opensmile

I am using Python with the library [opensmile](https://pypi.org/project/opensmile/). My target is to generate *.arff files to use in Weka3 ML-Tool.
My problem is, that It is rather unclear for me how to save the extracted features into an *.arff file.

for [example](https://audeering.github.io/opensmile-python/):

```
import opensmile

smile = opensmile.Smile(
    feature_set=opensmile.FeatureSet.ComParE_2016,
    feature_level=opensmile.FeatureLevel.Functionals,
)
y = smile.process_file('audio.wav')

//ToDo save y in arff
```

I should be possible since there are questions about the generated files eg:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929083/opensmile-generated-arff-file-format-is-not-recognized-by-weka-stating-unable-t).
However I can't find anything specific about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generating ARFF directly, you could generate a CSV file in a format that Weka can load it:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
import opensmile

# configure feature generation
smile = opensmile.Smile(
    feature_set=opensmile.FeatureSet.ComParE_2016,
    feature_level=opensmile.FeatureLevel.Functionals,
)

# the audio files to generate features from
audio_files = [
    '000000.wav',
    '000001.wav',
    '000002.wav',
]

# generate features
ys = []
for audio_file in audio_files:
    y = smile.process_file(audio_file)
    ys.append(y)

# combine features and save as CSV
data = pd.concat(ys)
data.to_csv('audio.csv', quotechar='\'', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

As a second (and optional) step, convert the CSV file to ARFF using the [CSVLoader](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/CSVLoader.html) class from the command-line:

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.core.converters.CSVLoader audio.csv > audio.arff
```

**NB:** You will need to adjust the paths to audio files, `weka.jar`, CSV and ARFF file to fit your environment, of course.

Comment: Thanks, that works

However, one class must be added at the end.